# How to find and change multiply th classes between n & n

Tags: jquery, html-table, parent, expand

I have some table structure:

```
    <tr class="row-2"><tr>
    <tr class="row-3">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-4">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-5">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-6">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-7"><tr>
    <tr class="row-8">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-9">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-10">..<tr>
    <tr class="row-11">..<tr>
...etc
```

for this example TR with classes "row-2" and "row-7" is parrent product link wich expand child rows.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('tr.parent')
        .css("cursor","pointer")
        .css("color","red")
        .attr("title","Click to expand/collapse")
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle();
        });
    $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
});
</script>
```

**Rows -3...-6 is child of row-2**
and
**Rows -8...-11 is child of row-7**

How  can I find row-2, row-7, etc then add second class "parent" and ID similar class (id="row-2", id="row-7", etc)? Also I need add in each **TR** between **row-2** and **row-7** class equal previous parent row. In bottom line I need  something like this:

```
        <tr class="row-2 parent" id="row-2"><tr>
        <tr class="row-3 child-row2">..<tr>
        <tr class="row-4 child-row2">..<tr>
        <tr class="row-5 child-row2">..<tr>
        <tr class="row-6 child-row2">..<tr>
        <tr class="row-7 parent" id="row-7"><tr>
        <tr class="row-8 child-row7">..<tr>
        <tr class="row-9 child-row7">..<tr>
        <tr class="row-10 child-row7">..<tr>
        <tr class="row-11 child-row7">..<tr>
..etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to do a two-pass on all rows, to set up the required classes and id's. In the first pass, add an id same as the class name, and also add the `parent` class to row-2, and row-7. In the second pass, find each `.parent` row, and add `child-<id>` class to their siblings until the next parent. Instead of hard-coding the values for row-2 and row-7, this assumes that all header items are contained inside a `<th>` element, instead of a `<td>` element.

Here's some code: http://jsfiddle.net/vYTW2/

```
/**
 * Do a two pass on all rows to set them up.
 * In the first pass, add the same id as class, and
 * add the "parent" class to the row.
 *
 * Assuming all product header rows contain a
 * <th> element
 */
$('table tr th').each(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent('tr');
    var id = row.attr('class');
    row.attr('id', id);
    row.addClass('parent');
});

/**
 * In the second pass, run through all header rows
 * (that have the class parent) and mark all next siblings
 * with class "child-rowX" until we see the next parent row.
 */
$('tr.parent').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var className = 'child-' + id;
    $(this).nextUntil('.parent').addClass(className);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But i look today into my table code. i don't have TH in parent rows. All rows generated only with TR class="row-X"

Here is what i need http://jsfiddle.net/KUyb8/
Here is what i have http://jsfiddle.net/YVqdS/ (generated table)

Comment: the only thing that looks differentiable is the `-` in the td columns, which looks too fragile. If you already know the header rows, you can run the first pass on each of them individually. for ex.) `$('.row-2, .row-9').each(function() {`, instead of looking for `<th>`